# Check Static Range block does not recognize variable in base workspace

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model with a [Check Static Range](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/checkstaticrange.html) block in it. In my base workspace I have a variable called `myNum=3`. Inside the Check Static Range block, there is an edit box called 'Simulation callback when assertion fails'. In this edit box I wrote `disp(num2str(myNum))`. What I expect is to see the value of myNum displayed in command window when an assertion occurs. Instead I get "**Error evaluating 'AssertionFcn' callback of Checks_SRange block... Undefined function or variable 'myNum'.**"

When I tried the same callback with the [Assertion](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/assertion.html) block, it worked without problems. How can I make the Check Static Range block recognize my variables in workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Check Static Range blocks have an Assertion block underneath a mask.  The Simulink callback string is evaluated in the mask workspace, instead of the base workspace which is why you're seeing the error.  Try this instead to force evaluation in the base workspace,

disp(num2str(evalin('base','myNum')))

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Matlab here to test. Did you put quotes around the content of the edit box ? Did 'disp(''3'')' works ? (with double single quotes since you're in a string)